# Can I remove the title completely?

Tags: powershell, powercli

Is there a method how I can remove the License title?

This is part of my command in my script:

```
Get-VMHost -Name test.test.local | Select LicenseKey
```

**Output:**

```
LicenseKey

----------  

M023J-ZYH06-88Y88-078RK-CR47M
```

I want to remove the `"LicenseKey"` title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-ExpandProperty` -

```
Get-VMHost -Name test.test.local | Select -ExpandProperty LicenseKey
```

**OR**

```
(Get-VMHost -Name test.test.local).LicenseKey
```